# Power measurement on neutral instead of line

Tags: analog, current-measurement, power-meter

what is the advantage or disadvantage of measuring the power on neutral insted of line in a single phase wiring. Generally I have observed that metering chip is given input from line to its Vin or Iin. But some designs use neutral metering instead of line metering. What is the pros/cons of using neutral metering?
Regards,
Shreyas.

Comment: On balanced three phase lines, measuring neutral will not be as satisfying for the power company.

Comment: What a power company wants is ideally the same current passing in each of the three phases (load distributed equally across each phase), if it's not balanced perfectly then you'll end up with a non zero neutral current, I always understood the power companies don't like that, and if the neutral current is over a threshold, they will penalise you for it.

Comment: What is the relevance of 3ph on either of the above comments. The OP clearly states "single phase" in his/her question.

Comment: Because the OP's question is clearly vague and I think it's important he understand what 3 phase is and where neutral line comes from, as this may help his understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Power is volts multiplied by amps so you need to simultaneously measure the voltage between live and neutral and the current flowing in live OR neutral.

Saying that power measurement is "neutral metering instead of line metering" misses the point about power measurement. You cannot measure power from one wire going to a load.

You can measure current on one wire and it will be the same on either wire assuming no leakage to earth. But given that leakage from live wire to earth is probably bigger than neutral wire to earth, current measurements using the live wire will be preferred.

Comment: One *could* measure voltage drop across a series-connected low-value resistor in the neutral line, however that is a bad idea.

Comment: @rdtsc what point are you trying to make sir?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between three phase and single phase supplies. Nearly all electricity generated by large power stations is three phase. But the appliances in your home are single phase.

A voltage is always measure between two points, it is a potential difference.
So there are three conductors which are phase conductors and a neutral line.

So you can measure the voltage between phase-to-phase, or between phase-neutral.
And there is a big difference!!

Without going through all the mathematical analysis (which uses complex number theory): if you have a phase line voltage (or line voltage) of 240 Volts RMS (if you're in America I know it's lower, but 240V RMS is what we used to use here in the UK), then the phase-to-phase voltage is 415Volts (not 480 or 400, but 415V).

The phase-to-neutral voltage is 240 volts.  As I said,a big difference!

Neutral metering? It comes down to what your installation is, if you're in a residential property where there's a neutral line, then you probably are interested in the power dissapation of the load, which is connected between the phase and neutral.

If you're in an office block or factory, then the property might be fed with a three phase supply and you might be interested in both, current (and power) between phase-to-phase, and phase-to-neutral.

Comment: The OP clearly states "single phase wiring" in his question so why all the 3 ph stuff? If you live in the UK you should know that the standard voltage is 230V AC with the permissible voltage range being 207 Volts to 253 Volts.

Comment: "but 240V RMS is what we used to use here in the UK", perhaps you missed that statement, but it does state "what we used to have here". I specifically made reference to 240V because I know all the figures for 240V and I did also state "without going through all the mathematical analysis". I was simply, clearly, using 240V as an example to avoid going through the calculations for 120 or 230V.

Comment: OK I missed your "used to use" and read it as "use"!